# how to add the Postgresql JDBC driver jar to the classpath Within the Spark Shell?

Tags: postgresql, apache-spark, jdbc

I am trying to add Postgresql jar to spark shell using
"scala> :require < path_to_postgresql-42.0.0.jar >" but it showing error
"< console >:1: error: ';' expected but double literal found"
any suggestion ??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are some way to add your dependencies

#### 1st add package as dependency

Spark will pull package from maven center for you

```
spark-shell --packages org.postgresql:postgresql:42.0.0
```

#### 2nd add jars to your spark shell

Change the path to your case

```
spark-shell --jars /YOUR/PATH/postgresql-42.0.0.jar
```

Answer (score 0):

Is there a way to verify setting up your class path is successful or not.